# Add an autoincrement primary key to a table created with a SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, syntax, primary-key, create-table

This is a syntax question, I don't know if what I'm thinking is possible. I can't find anything about it.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS newTable
SELECT something1, something2, something3 FROM someTable;
```

Using this syntax to create a new table, can I add a primary key to this? Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS newTable
SELECT id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, something1, something2, something3 FROM someTable;
```

I have a large and complex dynamic query that returns me te exact results I need. All that's left is to add these results an autoincrement primary key!
Because the query is dynamic, I don't know the number of columns I'll get, so I can't just:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS newTable;
CREATE TABLE newTable(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  something1 VARCHAR(255),
  something2 VARCHAR(255),
  something3 VARCHAR(255)
)  ENGINE=MEMORY;
```

Thanks in advance for any given advice!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you will have to run multiple steps to do this:

- Create a table with the primary key
- Add the columns to this table using a stored procedure (could be merged with step 1)

To do this you use the information schema. This will look as follows (dummy code, no mysql handy to debug anything):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE create_table(table_name VARCHAR(200))
BEGIN
  declare cursor table_columns as SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, 
    IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_DEFAULT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE table_name = 'table_name'
  LOOP
     concatenate create table statement
  END LOOP;
  execute create table statement

END
```